# How to append JTextArea from an outer class?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have 3 classes, a Frame class, a Panel class and an Algorithm class. The Frame is created first and it contains the panel class, the panel then starts the algorithm with the press of a button. The panel has a JTextArea log, which the algorithm has to append. I tried passing the Panel, so that it can access it, but no luck. Tried passing the JTextArea itself, no luck either. Even wrote a function, which the Algorithm could call to append, still nothing.Where is the catch here?

The code follows, hope it's not too much:
P.S. The code contains a FileLoader class, but that just load a file.

Frame:

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;


  import java.util.LinkedList;
    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
    import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ClusteringSelection extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    LinkedList<Record> table;
    KMeansUI kMeansUI;

public void run()
{
    StartUI();
}

public void StartUI()
{
    JTabbedPane tab1=new JTabbedPane();

    tab1.addTab("K-Means", kMeansUI=new KMeansUI(this));
    tab1.addTab("Aglomerative", new JPanel());
    add(tab1);
    JLabel status=new JLabel();
    status.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
    add(status, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setSize(320,320);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
ClusteringSelection()
{
    FileLoader loader=new FileLoader(this);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new ClusteringSelection();

}
}
```

Panel:

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class KMeansUI extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    ClusteringSelection mainWindow;
    JTextArea log;
    KMeans kMeans;
    JTextField centroids;

    public void UpdateLog(String text)
    {
        log.append(text+"\n");
    }

    public void run()
    {
        kMeans=new KMeans(mainWindow.table, Integer.parseInt(centroids.getText()), KMeansUI.this);
    }

    public void StartUI()
    {
        centroids=new JTextField();
        log=new JTextArea(" ");

        log.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));

        JScrollPane logScrool=new JScrollPane();
        logScrool.add(log);
        logScrool.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        JButton start=new JButton("Start");

        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                run();
                //kMeans=new KMeans(mainWindow.table, Integer.parseInt(centroids.getText()), KMeansUI.this);
            }
        });

    JLabel cenLabel=new JLabel("Count:");
    JRadioButton euclede=new JRadioButton("Eucledean");
    JRadioButton manhattan=new JRadioButton("Manhattan");
    JRadioButton pearsons=new JRadioButton("Pearson's");

    ButtonGroup messure=new ButtonGroup();
    messure.add(euclede);
    messure.add(manhattan);
    messure.add(pearsons);

    GroupLayout layout=new GroupLayout(this);
    setLayout(layout);

    layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
    layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

    layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(cenLabel)
                                .addComponent(centroids,20,20,20))
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(euclede))
                                        .addComponent(manhattan)
                                        .addComponent(pearsons)
                                        .addComponent(start))
                .addComponent(logScrool)

            );

    layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(cenLabel)
                                .addComponent(centroids,20,20,20)
                                )
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(euclede)
                                        .addComponent(manhattan)
                                        .addComponent(pearsons)
                                        .addComponent(start))))
                .addComponent(logScrool));

    setVisible(true);
}
KMeansUI(ClusteringSelection mainWindow)
{
    this.mainWindow=mainWindow;
    StartUI();
}
}
```

The algorithm, which works fine, except doesn't append.

```
  import java.util.LinkedList;

public class KMeans implements Runnable{

    LinkedList<Record> table;
    LinkedList<Centroid> centroidList;
boolean clusterStop=false;
int precision=10000000;
int centroidCount;
double time, iterCount=0;
KMeansUI kMeansUI;

public void run()
{
    while(clusterStop==false)
    {
        UpdateRecords(centroidList);
        UpdateClusters();
        iterCount++;

        for(int i=0;i<centroidCount;i++)
        {
            int count=0;
            for(int j=0;j<table.size();j++)
            {
                if(table.get(j).type==i)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Cluster "+(i+1)+" has "+count+" records.");
            //log.append("Cluster "+(i+1)+" has "+count+" records.");
            kMeansUI.UpdateLog("Cluster "+(i+1)+" has "+count+" records.");
        }
    }
    Output();
}

KMeans(LinkedList<Record> table, int centroidCount, KMeansUI kMeansUI)
{
    this.kMeansUI=kMeansUI;
    time=System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.table=table;
    this.centroidCount=centroidCount;
    CreateCentroids();
    run();
}

public void UpdateClusters()
{
    clusterStop=true;
    for(int i=0;i<centroidList.size();i++) //staiga pa centroidiem
    {
        for(int j=0;j<table.get(0).values.size();j++) //staiga pa kolonnam
        {
            double sum=0;
            double count=0;
            for(int k=0;k<table.size();k++) //staiga pa rindam
            {
                if(centroidList.get(i).type==table.get(k).type)
                {
                    sum+=table.get(k).values.get(j);
                    count++;
                }

            }
            if(centroidList.get(i).dimVal.get(j)!=(double) Math.round(((1/count)*sum)*precision)/precision)
            {
                clusterStop=false;
            }
            centroidList.get(i).dimVal.set(j, (double) Math.round(((1/count)*sum)*precision)/precision);

        }

    }
}

public void UpdateRecords(LinkedList<Centroid> centroidList)
{
    for(int i=0;i<table.size();i++)
    {
        table.get(i).Update(centroidList);
    }
}

public void CreateCentroids()
{
    centroidList=new LinkedList<Centroid>();
    for(int i=0;i<centroidCount;i++)
    {
        centroidList.add(new Centroid(table.get(0).values.size(),i));
    }
}

public void Output()
{
    LinkedList<String> types=new LinkedList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<table.size();i++)
    {
        if(!types.contains(table.get(i).realType))
        {
            types.add(table.get(i).realType);
        }   
    }       
    for(int i=0;i<centroidCount;i++) //staiga pa centroidiem
    {       
        for(int j=0;j<types.size();j++) //staiga pa klasem
        {
            int count=0;
            for(int k=0;k<table.size();k++) // staiga pa rindam
            {
                if(table.get(k).type==i && table.get(k).realType.equals(types.get(j)))
                {
                        count++;    
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Centroid "+(i+1)+" has "+count+" of type "+types.get(j));
            //log.append("Centroid "+(i+1)+" has "+count+" of type "+types.get(j));
            kMeansUI.UpdateLog("Centroid "+(i+1)+" has "+count+" of type "+types.get(j));
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<centroidCount;i++)
    {
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<table.size();j++)
        {
            if(table.get(j).type==i)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Cluster "+i+" has "+count+" records.");
        //log.append("Cluster "+i+" has "+count+" records.");
        kMeansUI.UpdateLog("Cluster "+i+" has "+count+" records.");
    }

    time=System.currentTimeMillis()-time;
}

}
```

Comment: please include the import statements on top of each class

Comment: what are `Centroid` and `Record`?

Comment: Record is an object, which the table list contains. Centroid is a similar object, nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: i understand but it would help including the code or at least substituting the classes for some type already included which would not alter the behavior in case we wanted to compile your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of : `logScrool.add(log);` use the following line to add log to `JScrollPane`:
`logScrool.setViewportView(log);`

Comment: @MustSeeMelons: The `add` methods are inherited from `java.awt.Container`, and the `addImpl` method is inherited from `javax.swing.JComponent`. These should be used for internal use only. To add something to a JScrollPane after it's been constructed you should use its `JViewport` instead. The `JViewport` provides a window, or "viewport" onto a data source -- for example, a text file. That data source is the "scrollable client" (aka data model) displayed by the JViewport view. `setViewportView(Component view)` Creates a viewport if necessary and then sets its view.

Comment: @MustSeeMelons: To know more about `setViewportView` look at here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewportView%28java.awt.Component%29